# Why is Controller.RouteData.Route null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display a small panel during debugging in my application with various miscellaneous functionality. One thing i want it to contain is information about the current route.

I tried to look at `Controller.RouteData` but some of the properties were null.

```
 RouteData.Route          - null
 RouteData.RouteHandler   - null
 RouteData.Values         - has expected values corresponding to the URL
```

How do I get the value of 'Route' ?

I did see this post about [URL debugging](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx), but I don't think that helps because although I'm writing a debugging console I want the 'runtime' values and don't want to put in an extra layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but still... you would like to to have the route-variables?

then you might get them via

```
ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")
```

The name of the routevalue comes from the routing where you define all variables.

So you can access to Controller, Action, ID, whatever you have in the routing.

Comment: @griti i dont rememebr exactly the situation but I'm no longer having the problem. RouteData.Route now has a value. I'm not sure if this changed for RTM or MVC 2 Preview 2. I dont think the problem was not being able to find the 'controller' name, but having a Route object